# Can string-based user-defined literals be strongly typed?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, user-defined-literals

The new user-defined literal concept in C++ suggests some very interesting uses of string-literals, such as:

```
"Goodbye %s world"_fmt("cruel");
"Goodbye %s world"_fmt(123); // Error: arg 1 must be convertible to const char*

R"(point = \((\d+), (\d+)\))"_re; // Builds DFA at compile-time.

typedef table<
    column<"CustId"_name   , std::string>,
    column<"FirstName"_name, std::string>,
    column<"LastName"_name , std::string>,
    column<"DOB"_name      , date       >
> Customer;
```

However, when I build these kinds of constructs in gcc, e.g.:

```
template <char... Chars> Name<Chars...> operator "" _name() {
    return Name<Chars...>();
}

auto a = 123_name;    // OK
auto b = "abc"_name;  // Error
```

I get the following error:

```
…unable to find string literal operator ‘operator"" _name’ with ‘const char [4]’, ‘long unsigned int’ arguments
```

From reading around, I'm guessing that the variadic-template form is not available to UDLs derived from string literals.

1. Is it in fact the case that string literals cannot be resolved using the variadic template form?
2. If so, does anyone have any insight into why such a useful form of UDL was left out of the standard?

Comment: What exactly is useful about creating a new type for every literal, types that would be entirely distinct from one-another?

Comment: @NicolBolas: In the examples shown, you *want* different literals to have different types. Moreover, the final type of a literal wouldn't necessarily be a naïve concatenation of its characters. For instance, `"freq: %g Hz" world"_fmt(44000)` might resolve to something like `Formatter<double>("freq: ", " Hz")(44000)` by means of metaprogramming.

Comment: That would also mean that you *cannot* pass it something that isn't a number. So you couldn't pass it something that it might use `operator<<` to convert into a stream, thus removing the possibility of customizing data types.

Comment: Nice examples of usage of user-defined literals.

Comment: @NicolBolas: If you mean that the `%g` is too constraining, that's easily solvable: `"value(%<)"_fmt(t)` could resolve to something like `format("value(", stream_format(t), ")")`, which would in turn invoke `Formatter<StreamFormat<T>>("value(", ")")(t)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are right. String literals cannot be used with the variadic template form (§2.14.8/5):

> If `L` is a *user-defined-string-literal*, let *str* be the literal
>   without its *ud-suffix* and let *len* be the number of code units in
>   *str* (i.e., its length excluding the terminating null character). The literal `L` is treated as a call of the form
>
> ```
> operator "" X (str, len)
> ```

I have shuffled through the proposal papers (the latest of which I could find was [N2750](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2750.pdf)) and could not find an explanation for not allowing the use of the variadic template form.

Comment: Could it be something as trivial as concurrent development of the two features which prevented one from using the other ?

Comment: @MatthieuM. I don't think so. I can't find evidence of them being developed separately (they're always together in the same paper). To be honest, when I saw the variadic form the very first thing that came to mind was the kind of ideas the OP showcases in the answer. I'd like to assume the committee saw some potential problem in this. Either that or an very annoying oversight.

Comment: All of the user defined literals that allow the use of the variadic form are limited to the basic source character set (simply because the grammar doesn't allow anything else in ints or floats). String literals don't have that limitation, so with a multibyte source/execution encoding you have c-chars in the string literal that may not be representable as individual chars. That might have something to do with the decision not to allow the variadic form with string literals.

Comment: I think the committee saw the variadic form as an option for numeric literals that would admit compile-time evaluation.  I think they were thinking "number" not string.

Answer (score 2):

N3599, which allows this, has been implemented in gcc and clang.

```
template<class CharT, CharT... chars>
int operator ""_suffix(){
    return 42;
}
```